# Remove focus from TextField when the keyboard is dismissed

Tags: flutter

It seems that a TextField does not lose the focus when the keyboard is dismissed. That makes the cursor continually blink, and more seriously, when the main window gets focus again, for example, after showing a dialogue box, the keyboard pops up again. Can I make the TextField lose focus when the keyboard is dismissed?

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Example"),),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Test"), onPressed: () => onButtonClick(context))
      ],
    ),
  )),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this when clicking on the button:

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

and if you have a textEditingController (which I recommend using) you can call to clear the field

```
_textEditingController.clear();
```

but you have to create the controller first:

```
final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

and when you create your TextField:

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Example"),
    controller: _textEditingController,
),
```

Comment: The other person also mentioned adding a controller, but adding a controller does not seem to automatically fix it. If calling controller.clear() removes the focus, am I supposed to call it when the keyboard is closed? But how can I get notified for that? Adding the unfocus to the button does not seem very good, because I would have to add that too all other controllers, if there is more than just one button.

Comment: @DamnVegetables controller.clear() just clears the text from your TextField. For your problem, try install the keyboard_visibility package, where you can add a listener to listen for keyboard changes. You can also dismiss the keyboard from the textfield like in onSubmitted()

Answer (score -1):

Use `TextEditingController`:

First Initialise :

`TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();`

code:

`TextField(controller: _textController),`